# PHP не видит ajax запрос

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

js(jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'createproject.php',
        data:{name:'Alan'},
        success:function(){
            alert('Данные отправлены')
        }
    })
```

В файле createproject.php код:

```
var_dump($_POST['name']);
```

Выводится NULL, причем  при отправке ajax запроса срабатывает success
,но PHP не видит запрос.

P.S(использую openserver)

Comment: "Выводится NULL" - где именно?

Comment: @u_mulder в createproject.php

Comment: Ну так получается что сначала отдельно происходит ajax-запрос, а потом отдельно - переход на `createproject.php`?

Comment: @u_mulder а как можно реализовать редирект чтобы выводилось $_POST[“name”]

Comment: Судя по коду, вы не выводите ответ ajax запроса (вы выводите "Данные отправлены"). В таком случае откуда вам известно что POST запрос не был получен (и что было выведено NULL)? Как вы проверяете это?

Comment: success:function(data){alert(data); // выведет полученный ответ от php

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url:'createproject.php',
    data:{name:'Alan'},
    success:function(){
        alert('Данные отправлены')
    }
})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]